# Футтер в шаблоне на Android

Tags: java, android

Как правильно сверстать шаблон на Андройд?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема возникает в верстке нижний части, что бы картинка и футтер поместились на экран, при этом под разные устройства.

Comment: Как вы уже пытались это реализовать и что не получается (какая возникает проблема)? Код разметки приложите.

Comment: да вот в этом то и дело, нету мыслей как реализовать нижнюю часть, верстаю черед linear layout

Answer (score 4):

Для такой верстки обычно используется указание весов элементов - `android:layout_weight`:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```